# Why can't one use pointer to char pointers instead of array of char pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

When I try the second option in the following code to initialize `names`, I get a segmentation fault. I guess there is something conceptually incorrect with the second option. Any ideas?

```
 char *names[] = {
            "Alan", "Frank",
            "Mary", "John", "Lisa"
        };

 char **names = {
            "Alan", "Frank",
            "Mary", "John", "Lisa"
        };
```

Comment: `char name[] = "Allan";`
`char **names = &name;`

Comment: Maybe tell us WHY you're so into **. They have little use beside return from functions via arguments.

Comment: @Agent_L I was following along the book "Learn C The Hard Way" (http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/learn-c-the-hard-waych16.html), where there is an exercise to "Rewrite all the array usage in this program so that it's pointers."

Comment: This is very cryptical instruction. Pointers have to point to an element of an array for the ++, -- and [i] magic to work.
I believe he meant to access all arrays via walking pointers (++) instead of [i]. Pointers are just a way for accessing arrays, not full replacement of them.

Comment: @Agent_L Yeah, I guess you are right. Was confused at first reading the rather cryptic instruction. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. In first case, you have an array of pointers. Each pointer points to a separate item(Alan, Frank...)

The second declaration

```
char **names;
```

implies that names is a pointer to a pointer[You cannot initialize a set of strings like this]. As in

```
char *str = "hello"
char **names = &str;
```

Answer (score 2):

It has a completely different memory layout.

Your first example is an array of pointers. It occupies 5 times the size of a `char *`.

Your 2nd example, however, is a pointer to a location where one or more `char *` are to be expected. It is not possible to initialize it the way you do it.

Comment: Thanks, what would be the correct way to initialize for the second option

Comment: The first way is the correct way. char **names is not an array. It is a pointer to a pointer  and thus can hold the address of a pointer as I had posted above.

Comment: @stressed_geek You can have a `char**` (2nd way) point to an array (1st way). But first, you have to initialize it. `char * names[]={...}; char ** n2 = &names;` could be a way to go...

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you have an array of `char*`. This means, you have allocated memory for 5 char* variables (the entries of the array), neatly sitting in memory one right after another. Also, each of them is initialized to beginning of each string.

In the second case, you have ONE pointer of char** type. You have only enough memory for one pointer.

(I've skipped discussing the memory allocated for each string. It may be same in both cases but it's irrelevant here)

Answer (score 0):

It does not cause a seg fault with gcc. However attempting the same this with an integer array could possibly illustrate why it does not make a lot of sense:

```
char* names[] = { "Dennis", "Richie" };
char** more_names = { "Sarah", "O'connor" };

printf("Name: %s %s\n", names[0], names[1] );
printf("Name: %s %s\n", more_names + 0, more_names + 1);

int numbers[] = { 0, 1 };
int x = 2, y = 3;
int* more_numbers = { &x, &y };

printf("Numbers: %d, %d\n", numbers[0], numbers[1] );
printf("Numbers: %d, %d\n", *(more_numbers + 0), *(more_numbers + 1));
```

The weird thing is that this example actually produces the expected results for the integer array. However gcc does produce a warning.